# How to create identical activities in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity

Im developing an application with quite a number of activities.

The activities are content wise identical, containing 2 buttons and 2 textfields.

The problem I have is that I want every activity to look like every other in placement, since their content will be different.

Im using the Eclipse IDE

How do I approach this problem?

Comment: What more do you need? I want the elements to be placed at the exact same place as the other activities

Comment: Why don't you use one activity and change the content as required?  What's the point of creating multiple activities?  You need to make your question more precise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should share one layout with different activities. Create a layout (xml file) and then use it for all the activities that you want to look identical. Just change setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout); in onCreate().

Comment: That sounds like a good solution. But Im insecure about one thing, and its about the elements ID in each activity, should every ID be different ? Because every element has the exact same function, but different content

Comment: Same ID, then in each activity call them with findViewById() and use setText() or what you need to add the content. Don't use xml to add the content (do it in the activity), just the basic graphic elements (width, height, ...)